# Spotfire Cross table visualization - Coloring the columns based on column header

Tags: spotfire

I have a cross table visualization as shown below,

```
Product Group1  Group2  Group3
ABC     1       ---     ---
EFG     ---     1       ---
HIJ     2       2       1
KLM     3       3       1
NOP     4       4       1
```

Is it possible to color the columns based on column header, for example i want the column "Group 1" to be coloured in Yellow, "Group 2" to be coloured in pale green and group 3 to be coloured in Green.

Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the properties of the cross table and then look at Colors, you can see on the top of Colors, the header **color by**. By default this stands on Cell Values. You can change this to your header column. Next you have to add group 1 to the Color Scheme Groupings and set this color to Yellow with color mode fixed. If you do the same for the other Groups, your cross table will be colored as you want.

Comment: Is it possible to get the column header "Group1", "Group2" and "Group3" to be coloured as well??

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But maybe in spotfire 7.x. I haven't worked with that version yet.